# Comparison between different Ukulele exam boards / certifications

Tags: ukulele, exam-grades

I am looking for Ukulele exam boards and I can find LCM and RockSchool. I wonder if I am missing any of if because Ukulele is quite a niche instrument there aren't any others in Europe?

Thanks.

Comment: There is also MTB Exams who offer grades from Preliminary to grade 8

Comment: Thanks @LindsayHIggs - that's useful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victoria College of Music and Drama (London), coupled with the Ukulele Society of Great Britain have an exam system - maybe only in UK, not Europe. RGT (LCM) has been providing uke exams for nearly 10 years, not sure about Rockschool.

Comment: Thanks - it seems they also do exams via zoom so VCM would work as well. I guess I will look at the curriculum of the 3 options and compare them.